# changing folder name recursively using regex (shell)

Tags: regex, shell, recursion

So I want to change the name of a specific folder recursively. However, that folder isn't always at the same depth or position. I want to change the folder name from `variables` to `constant`.

So the `variables` folders might be located at depth 2, and/or 3, and/or 4, and/or 5, 6, etc... I do not know that

It might be

`/var/me/variables/.../.../`

or

`/var/me/..../..../.../variables/...`

or

`/var/variables/..../variables/.../../variables/`

What I want again is, WHEREVER there is a folder called `variables`, change its name to `constant`

I did the following code,  but it doesn't work

```
find var -type d -exec echo `echo "{}" | sed 's/variables/constant/g'` \;
```

any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fun! Here are my two cents:

`find . -depth -type d -name variables -execdir mv -T {} constant \;`

**Rationale:**

- `-depth` avoids changing a path `find` later descends into; probably can be omitted.
- `-execdir` avoids the need to play games with entire paths, so we can operate only on the directory basename
- passing the `-T` option to `mv` makes it bail if a directory `constant` should already exist

Comment: does this code modify the permission `chmod` of some directories by any chance? Because some directories cannot be opened unless I'm root. However, this was not the case before... PS the code works great

Comment: @Matin Nope, I don't see how this command could mess up the permissions. And, nice that it works for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to call `mv`, not `echo`:

```
find var -type d -name "*variables*" -exec mv {} `echo "{}" | sed 's/variables/constant/g'` \;
```

The above assumes you have directories with with string "variables" in names. If you are after directories which are called precisely "variables", then it could be a bit simpler:

```
find var -type d -name variables -exec mv {} constant \;
```

Comment: I get few dozens of this error when I try your code `mv: cannot move ‘var/config/me/1.0/variables’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘var/config/me/1.0/variables/variables’`

Comment: Did you try the first option, with `sed`? Perhaps this is better.

Comment: the second line I tried it too. it gives me this. `mv: cannot move ‘var/config/me/2.1/variables’ to ‘foo/variables’: Directory not empty`

Answer (score 0):

Try this find command:

```
find var -name "*variables*" -type d -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1//variables/constant}"' - '{}' \;
```

Comment: didn't change folder names.. :(

Comment: put an `echo` before `mv` and see what it prints.

Comment: inside the `''` or outside?

Comment: like this: `find var -name "*variables*" -type d -exec bash -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1/variables/constant}"' - '{}' \;`

Comment: none of the folders changed and i got this message printed a lot of times for different folder. `mv var/config/me/1.0/variables var/config/variables/1.0/constant`

Comment: @anubhava: Can you please explain to me what your `$1` does expand to?

Comment: `$1` becomes the name of the file found by find command whereas `"${1//variables/constant}"` is filename with `variables` replaced by `constant`

Comment: I understood that, but not why `$1` was supposed to expand like you say. See it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `find` with `rename`

```
find /var -type d -name 'variables' -type d -exec rename 's/variables/constant/' {} \;
```